# Find total number of ordered and positive integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ such that $xyz$ is a factor of $ 1800$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find total number of ordered and positive integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ such that $xyz$ is a factor of $ 1800$.

I used prime factorization, added $1$ to each exponent to account for the zeroes, multiplied them, and got $36$. Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: You only found that there are $36$ such tuples of the form $(1,1,d)$. There is more to do.

Comment: Markup and margin ...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What you did was that you found the number of factors of $1800$. Unfortunately, that is not enough, since it only corresponds to the case where two of $x,y,z$ are $1$. Since these are either of the form $(x,1,1),(1,y,1)$ or $(1,1,z)$, there are $36\times 3-2$ ways at least (removing the overcounting of $(1,1,1)$). Unfortunately, it is quite hard to count the answer in this way. Instead, observe that $xyz\mid 1800$ implies there exists some $w$ so that $wxyz=1800=2^33^25^2$. Consider the prime factorisations of $w,x,y$ and $z$, and it is clear that the exponent of $2$ in each of $w,x,y,z$ must sum to $3$ and similarly for the exponents of $3$ and $5$. Now, count the number of ways four nonnegative integers sum to $3$, and similarly for $2$, then multiply the results together.

Comment: You are counting $(1,1,1)$ 3 times

Comment: @taritgoswami Thank you, it is now fixed.